# Python3.7 get diff of multiple files in two directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stuck on the basic logic I need to create this script. I'm trying to do a diff from the local server to a remote server. I have the diff code working for explicit filenames, but now I need to determine if the files are the same so I'm not doing the diff on two completely different files when I'm looping through the directory. I can't quite figure out the logic I need to use. Here is my setup:

```
source
|- test1.xml
|-- directory
|---- test2.xml
|---- test3.xml

remote
|- test1.xml
|-- directory
|---- test2.xml
|---- test4.xml
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can look through these directories, match which ones have the same file name, then do a diff on the ones with the same file name. So ultimately I get:

```
patched
    |- test1.xml
    |-- directory
    |---- test2.xml
    |---- test3.xml
    |---- test4.xml
```

Per answer and additional resources:

```
files = filecmp.dircmp('../source', '../repo')


def open_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines


def write_to_new_file(filename, result):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        lines = f.write(result)
        return lines


def report_file_diff(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files:
        print("DIFF file %s found in %s and %s" % (name,
                                                   dcmp.left, dcmp.right))
        fromfile = os.path.abspath(dcmp.left + '/' + name)
        tofile = os.path.abspath(dcmp.right + '/' + name)
        source = open_file(fromfile)
        repo = open_file(tofile)
        diff = difflib.unified_diff(source, repo, fromfile=fromfile, tofile=tofile, lineterm='\n')
        result = Colorize.color_diff(diff)
        print(''.join(result), end="")
        with open('why_is_this_not_working.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('Because you don\'t know what you are doing\n')
            f.write('Because you suck\n')
    for name in dcmp.left_only:
        print("ONLY SOURCE file %s found in %s" % (name, dcmp.left))
    for name in dcmp.right_only:
        print("ONLY REMOTE file %s found in %s" % (name, dcmp.right))
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        print(sub_dcmp)


report_file_diff(files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need in order to mange this is queue. First add root dir to queue and then run some code with logic below:

1. Pop item from queue.
2. List items in the destination (like dir command)
3. In the list (from step 2) there are 2 type of objects you need to handle

   1. ***files*** you can check if they exists in the source (by name or by binary shape (check them by hash)) (**location in the source should be the location queue**)
   2. ***folders*** adding its path to a queue and recheck from step 1
4. If any thing didn't exist in source (either in step 3.1 or 3.2) copy them (or any other operation you should do)

Comment: Awesome...thank you. I used this info, along with some other resources I found to create my code. Still working on writing the results, but I'll get that solved. I updated my question to show the current code.